# Simplifying nested promises and loops

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I'm building an angular app and i'm trying to understand better about promises
When i'm dealying with async calls (like $http) what i usually do is wrap them in a service then call them in my controllers like this:

```
...

function whatever(arguments) {
    dataService.getUser(arguments)
        .then(onUserComplete)
        .then(dataService.getExtra)
        .then(onExtraComplete)
        .catch(onError);

    function onUserComplete(user) {
        //do something with user
        ...
        // return user id (because we are
        // supposing that getExtra is
        // requiring an id as argument)
        return user.id;
    }

    function onExtraComplete(extra) {
        // do something with extra
        // no need to return anything,
        // we are the last element of the
        // chain.
    }

    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

...
```

This help me keeping every function understandable and maintenable, easy to read and consistent... at least until i need to deal with collection.
Suppose that i need to do the same thing as before, but instead of having one user, i'm getting the entire collection of user (and i still need to obtain the extra data of each single user).
What i did is this:

```
...

function whatever(arguments) {
    dataService.getUsers(arguments)
        .then(onUsersComplete)
        .catch(onError);

    function onUsersComplete(users) {
        users.forEach(function(user) {
            dataService.getExtra(user.id)
                .then(onExtraComplete)
                .catch(onError);
        });
    }

    ...
}

...
```

Is this the best that i can obtain trying to follow my coding style? 
Is even possible to resolve my problem with a single promise chain?
Thanks

Comment: Just an FYI: Even though JavaScript's hoisting will result in the functions to be known, many linters with default settings will complain about the functions not being defined before using them.

Comment: Your second code snippet gets all users in parallel, and when a user is received, you process it immediately. If that's what you intend your second snippet is correct.

Comment: @manonthemat yes, i know. I'm using Brackets with the Delkos Theme and it use a different color for methods already defined. In the real production code the functions are defined before being used :)

Comment: @tcooc pardon me, but are you sure about it? It seems that i get all users before then i process each of them sequentially instead of getting them in parallel

Comment: @Donbabbeo To clarify, you get all users, then process them in parallel (assuming `getExtra` is asynchronous).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all` ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) to wait for an array of promises.

```
dataService.getUsers(arguments)
    .then(users => users.map(
        user => dataService.getExtra( user.id )
    ))
    .then( Promise.all )
    .then( user_extra => /* get array with user data as result */ )
    .catch( onError );
```

We map users to an array of promises returned by your function, then use Promise.all to bundle all promises. In the next `.then()` all user extra data is loaded and provided in the result array.